# Visual Studio 2010 Professional issue creating new wpf project

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010

I am having trouble creating a new WPF Project in VS 2010 Professional.

Here's the error that I am getting:

[image]

[image]

Can somebody help me with this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: looks like your project template is corrupted. Reinstall Visual Studio

Comment: Agreed, the simplest fix is probably to reinstall Visual Studio on top of the existing installation. That will fix any corrupted by files by recopying them and add back anything that is missing. No use wasting a lot of time chasing down other possible fixes.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are not forced to reinstall visual studio.

First try `devenv /installvstemplates` in command line with administrator rights. This should restore your templates.